# How to get association rules with RHS more than length 1 in R

Tags: r, data-science, unsupervised-learning, apriori, arules

I am trying to understand the use of R to run the apriori algorithm to mine association rules.Referencing an online exam question with solutions provided on [Studocs Q2.2](https://www.studocu.com/en-au/document/university-of-queensland/data-mining/exam-2012-data-mining-questions-and-answers/145861), it is expected that I get 8 association rules which fulfill the minimum support and minimum confidence criteria. However, I tried to run it in R and I only got 7, the missing rule being `milk -> bread,butter`.

May I know if anyone knows what I can do to allow the R snippet to produce the 8th rule or any rule that has an RHS length of more than 1.

Here is the snippet of R code which contains the transaction data as described in the question and the use of `apriori`. Let me know if more information is required to solve the problem.

```
library('arules')
library('arulesViz')


dataset = list(
  c("Bread", "Butter", "Milk"),
  c("Bread", "Butter"),
  c("Beer", "Cookies", "Diapers"),
  c("Milk", "Diapers", "Bread", "Butter"),
  c("Beer", "Diapers")
)

Groceries = transactions(dataset)


itemsets <- apriori(Groceries,
                    parameter=list(
support=0.4, confidence = 0.7))


inspect(sort(itemsets, by = "support"))
```